# Is this the right way to implement Factory Method design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern

I have to implement a fee structure different for various franchise depending on certain  criteria. i make an Abstract Class for FranchiseFeeStructure

```
    public abstract class FranchiseFeeStructure {
        private BigDecimal registrationFee=1500;
        protected BigDecimal monthlyFee;

    public BigDecimal getMonthlyFees(){  
            return monthlyFee;  
        }

    public BigDecimal  calculateFee{
        //calculate fee here 
        return fee;
        }
}
```

Now for different structure i make classes which extends FranchiseFeeStructure like

```
public class ST1 extends FranchiseFeeStructure{
    @Override
     void getMonthlyFee(){
         monthlyFee=890;
     }

}
```

and ST2, ST3 and so on for various structures. and we have a class to have static factory method.

```
public class GetFeeStructureFactory {

    public static  FranchiseFeeStructure getFranchiseFeeStructure(String franchiseFeeStructureType){  

         if(franchiseFeeStructureType == null){  
          return null;  
         }  
       if(franchiseFeeStructureType.equalsIgnoreCase("ST1")) {  
              return new ST1();  
            }   
        else if(franchiseFeeStructureType.equalsIgnoreCase("ST2")){  
    /// so on...

    }
}
```

Now use it as

```
FranchiseFeeStructure franchiseFeeStructure = GetFeeStructureFactory.getFranchiseFeeStructure("ST1");
        franchiseFeeStructure.getMonthlyFee();
            franchiseFeeStructure.calculateFee();
```

Is this the right way to implement the method Factory pattern. Please tell me if i am wrong or any suggestion to make it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not so in the factory implementation. It's in the way your abstract class is implemented. It forces every caller to initialize the monthly fee, by calling a (badly named) method `getMonthlyFee()`. The caller shouldn't have to do that. And your abstract class should rely... on an abstract method to do that:

```
public abstract class FranchiseFeeStructure {
    private static final BigDecimal REGISTRATION_FEE = new BigDecimal(1500);

    public final BigDecimal calculateFee {
        BigDecimal monthlyFee = getMonthlyFee();
        // TODO compute
        return fee;
    }

    /**
     * Subclasses must implement this method to tell what their monthly fee is
     */
    protected abstract BigDecimal getMonthlyFee();
}

public class ST1 extends FranchiseFeeStructure {
    @Override
    protected BigDecimal getMonthlyFee(){
        return new BigDecimal(890);
    }
}
```

That way, the caller doesn't need to initialize the monthly fee. All it needs to do is

```
BigDecimal fee = FeeStructureFactory.getFranchiseFeeStructure("ST1").calculateFee();
```

Note that if the monthly fee is always a constant value, you don't even need an abstract class and multiple subclasses. All you need is a single class taking the monthly fee as a constructor argument.

Comment: Thanks Nizet, i really appreciate your response. off-course, i have to make getMonthlyFee as abstract method.

Comment: but not able to understand as your last line to make monthly fee as constructor argument. in my case monthly fee is different for different fee Structures

Comment: But if the monthly fee is constant for every subclass, you could simply make FranchiseFreeStructure not abstract, and `return new FranchiseFreeStructure(890)` or `return new FranchiseFreeStructure(122)` depending on the structure type. No need for a subclass to simply change a value. A subclass is useful to change behavior, i.e. provide different logic.

Comment: noted as you said, thanks but me i have various variables and their behaviors for different structures apart from monthly fee.

Answer (score 0):

Well yeah the idea is the same but you can improve your code. I will suggest an improvement according to me. I will present it with an interface and implementation not with abstract  class but the idea is the same.

```
interface FranchiseFee{
  BigDecimal getMonthlyFee();
  BigDecimal calculateFee():
}

public class CocaColaFee implements FranchiseFee{

   public BigDecimal getMonthlyFee(){
     return new BigDecimal("..");
   }

   public BigDeicaml calculateFee(){
     // do the calculation
   }

}

public class PepsiFee implements FranchiseFee{

   public BigDecimal getMonthlyFee(){
     return new BigDecimal("..");
   }

   public BigDeicaml calculateFee(){
     // do the calculation
   }

}

public FranchiseFeeFactoty {


// this is the easiest way to avoid if/else which makes the code awful. Also to use this you need to have default constructor, because as you can see you need additional code and it get's complicated.

//the other way is to use map but it's just a more convenient if/else approach

   public static FranchiseFee create(Class<? extends FranchiseFee> franchiseFeeType){

     try {
            return franchiseFeeType.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

   }
}
```

If you need anything else just ask for it :) i will try to help  you

Comment: If the caller needs to have a reference to the class (i.e. PepsiFee.class, for example) in order to get an instance, it might simply call the constructor directly. The point of a factory is to get an object from some unrelated value (a string, for example), without knowing which concrete type will be received.

Comment: Well i must disagree and i have no idea what you mean with reference wehn you can have a reference to an object but anyways. and nope you cannot because this way  no matter how many implementations you do you don't og to the factory method to add another stupid if. What if you have 10 implementations? You will have a bunch of ifs to get instances. Also the way you suggest if i change the string  in the factory method and you used to call it from somewhere i might broke your code without knowing.

Comment: I think you didn't understand. Suppose you receive some JSON object from a web page, and this JSON object contains the string "coke" or "pepsi". Now get the approporiate FranchiseFree instance based on this string. That's the whole point of the factory that the OP is trying to implement. Whatever the way you look at it, you'll have to implement something which, based on this string, will return the appropriate instance. And no, the JSON will not contain the name of a class, because the outside world doesn't need to care about the internal implementation of your application.